# Can peered VPCs use firewall rules that reference tags and service accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I have 2 VPCs peered together, `aaa` and `bbb`.

In `aaa` I have a VM `host-aaa` with a network tag `tag-aaa`, and in `bbb` I have a VM `host-bbb` with a network tag `tag-bbb`.

Can I create a firewall rule in `aaa` that *allows ingress* into `host-aaa` from `host-bbb` based on network tags?

That is, a firewall rule like

```
network: aaa
direction: ingress
action: allow
target-tag: tag-aaa
source-tag: tag-bbb
protocols: allow-all
```

When I create this rule, I don't observe it working. Same thing if I use service accounts as the target & source filters.  `host-bbb` cannot ping `host-aaa`.  *However* when I create a firewall rule that filters the source based on **IP Address**, then it works.  If I allow the IP range that `host-bbb` is in, then it allows ingress into `host-aaa`.

So, my question is:

Can I use service accounts and/or tags in firewall rules that are for cross-VPC traffic in a peered VPC setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags and service accounts are not usable across peered networks as per the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#tags_and_service_accounts_are_not_usable_across_peered_networks).

Comment: Sure enough - there it is!